# Error al momento de capturar un dato y realizar una operacion en JAVA

Tags: java

Buen día a todos,

Me gustaría que me ayudaran, estoy haciendo un programa sencillo de una cuenta en consola, el problema es que le pido al usuario nombre y tipo de operacion a realizar, si es retiro o consignar el programa debe realizar una accion. Si es consignar el programa solicita el monto y y lo suma al saldo de cuenta, sin embargo no se cual es el error pero no lo imprime, no suma el monto al saldo en cuenta y solo imprime el saldo, ayuda por favor, envio el codigo, la verdad soy muy nuevo programando.

Esta es la clase cuenta, la otra es el main, pero en el solo imprimo y pido los datos, no tiene relevancia.

```
public class Cuenta {

    private String titular;
    private double saldo;
    private double monto;
    private char ingresar = 'C';
    private char retirar = 'R';

    public Cuenta() {   // constructor con las variables sobrecargadas
        titular=null;
        saldo=500.0;
        monto=0.0;
    }

    public Cuenta(String titular, double saldo, double monto) {     // constructor con las variables por parametro

    }

    public double ingresar(double monto) {
        /*if(monto<0) {
            saldo=saldo;
        }else {
            this.saldo=saldo+monto;
        }*/
        this.saldo=saldo+monto;
        return saldo;
    }

    public double retirar(double monto) {
        if(saldo<monto) {
            saldo=0.0;
        }else {
            this.saldo=saldo-monto;
        }

        return saldo;
    }

    public void setTitular(String titular) {
        this.titular=titular;
    }

    public String getTitular() {
        return titular;
    }

    public void setMonto(double monto) {
        this.monto=monto;
    }

    public double getMonto() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setOperacion(char operacion) {

        if(operacion == ingresar) {
            ingresar(monto);
        }

        if(operacion == retirar) {
            retirar(monto);
        }

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Cuenta = "+getTitular()+" Saldo = "+getMonto();

    }

}
```

Comment: Pues viendo el código, creo que el main sí tiene relevancia. Podrías añadirlo?

Comment: Este constructor no inicializa nada: `public Cuenta(String titular, double saldo, double monto) {     // constructor con las variables por parametro

    }`... las variables se quedan _en el aire_.  `public Cuenta(String titular, double saldo, double monto) {     // constructor con las variables por parametro
this.titular=titular; this.saldo=saldo; this.monto=monto;
    }` Luego, si usas el método `toString` desde el `main` entonces, `getMonto` te está devolviendo el saldo inicial, debería ser: `public double getMonto() {
        return this.saldo;
    }` Es lo que veo, a simple vista.

Comment: Aunque `public double getMonto() {
        return this.saldo;
    }`  es una cosa confusa. **¿Por qué  lo llamas `getMonto` y haces return del saldo????** ¿qué quieres obtener, el monto o el saldo? Lo mismo ocurre con los otros métodos, a todos les falta `this`:  o sea: **`return this.saldo;`**

Comment: Hola, bueno los constructores son porque es un ejercicio de internet y estoy siguiendo la dinamica del ejercicio que dice declararlos, quiero traer el saldo ya que despues de la operacion escogida seria el resultado.

Comment: Este es el main.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainEjercicio1DDR {
 
 public static void main(String [] args) {
  
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  Cuenta c = new Cuenta();
  
  System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del titular");
  c.setTitular(sc.next());
    
  System.out.println("Ingrese la operacion a realizar\n"
    + "C (CONSIGNAR)"
    + "R (RETIRAR)");
  c.setOperacion(sc.next().charAt(0));
  
  System.out.println("Ingrese el monto de la Operacion");
  c.setMonto(sc.nextDouble());
  
  System.out.println(c.toString());
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el método `main` lanzas la operación antes de capturar el monto, por lo que el monto será siempre `0`.

Debes cambiar el orden:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Cuenta c = new Cuenta();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del titular");
    c.setTitular(sc.next());
    System.out.println("Ingrese el monto de la Operacion");
    c.setMonto(sc.nextDouble());
    System.out.println("Ingrese la operacion a realizar\n" + "C (CONSIGNAR)" + "R (RETIRAR)");
    c.setOperacion(sc.next().charAt(0));
    System.out.println(c.toString());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, hice lo que indicaste y funciono!!